# Find field length from one file and extract the same length of data from another fixed length file and store the field and data in new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have one file file1.dml and another fixed length data file file2.dat.
data in file1.dml be like

```
start
  integer(16) field1 ;
  string(1) filed2 ;
  string(80) filed3 ;
  decimal(16.2) field4;
  string(1) newline = "\n";
end;
```

data in file2.dat be like

```
12345678        ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                         1234567890
```

I need the output file like below

```
field1="12345678        "
filed2="A"
filed3="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                         "
field4="1234567890      "
newline="\n"
```

**I have written below function which accepts file1.dml and file2.dat and generate the exact result, but i want to simplify this using AWK, thanks in advance for any help**

```
function myfunc1
{
        if [ $1 == "" -a $2 == "" -a ! -f $1 -a ! -f $2 ]; then
                print "Input files not present"
        else


                dml_file=$1   #input parameter, dml file
                cntl_file=$2  #input parametr, dat file

                start_pos=1
                end_pos=0

                cat "$dml_file" | sed '1d' | sed '$d' | while IFS= read line
                do
                        counter=`echo $line | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1`
                        fld_name=`echo $line | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f2 | sed 's/;//g'`
                        #check decimal or not
                        if [[ $counter == +([0-9]) ]]; then
                                end_pos=$((counter+start_pos))
                        else
                                counter1=`echo $counter | cut -d'.' -f1`
                                counter=$counter1
                                end_pos=$((counter1+end_pos))
                        fi
                        newline_check=`echo $fld_name | grep -i 'newline' | wc -l`
                        if [ $newline_check -gt 0 ]; then
                                fld_name="newline"
                                fld_val="\n"
                                #write below line in one file
                                echo "$fld_name : \"$fld_val\""
                        else
                                fld_val=`cat $cntl_file | cut -c$start_pos-$end_pos`
                                #write below line in one file
                                echo "$fld_name : \"$fld_val\""
                        fi

                        start_pos=$((start_pos+counter))
                done
        fi
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far re: using `awk`? will `file2.dat` always be limited to a single line could `file1.dat` have more than one `start/end` block and if so what should the output look like? am I reading this right ... you want to ignore the `scale/.2` portion of `field4`?

Comment: using AWK i am able to get the field name and length, nothing else till now. file2.dat will be always a single line. there will always one start in the first line and end at the last line. scale 16.2 means, data length is 16 only, scale 2 can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `file2.dat` only has a single line I'd start by reading this into a variable so that we don't have to continually scan the file; eg:

```
$ IFS= read -r rawdata < file2.dat     # 'IFS=' needed in order to retain trailing white space
$ echo ".${rawdata}."                  # periods included to show that trailing white space retained
.12345678        ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                          1234567890      .
```

At this point we can pass the `rawdata` variable to an `awk` solution:

```
awk -v rd="${rawdata}" -F'[();=]' '

BEGIN { s = 1 ; nl = "\\n" }

/start|end/     { next }

/newline/       { gsub(/ /,"",$4)
                  nl = $4
                  next
                }

                { split($2,a,".")
                  len = a[1]

                  gsub(/ /,"",$3)
                  fname = $3

                  printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", fname, substr(rd,s,len)
                  s += len
                }

END   { printf "newline=%s\n", nl }
' file1.dat
```

Where:

- `-v rd="${rawdata}"` - define `awk` variable `rd` as containing the current value of `${rawdata}`
- `-F '[();=]'` - define 4 different input/field delimiters (`(`, `)`, `;`, `=`); `$2`=field length, `$3`=field name, `$4`=newline character(s)
- `BEGIN ( s = 1 ; nl= "\\n" }` - initialize our `s`tart position in `rd` and a default `newline` character (`\n`)
- `/start|end/ { next }` - ignore lines that contain `start` or `end`
- `/newline/ ....` - if we see the pattern `newline` then remove spaces and set `nl` to this new value (`$4`)
- `next` - stop processing for current line and go to next line of input
- **NOTE**: for the rest of the lines in our input file:
- `split($2,a,".")` / `len = a[1]` - split the 'length' field (`$2`) based on a period delimiter into array `a`, then set `len` to the first element of array `a`
- `gsub(/ /,"",$3)` / `fname = $3` - remove white space from the field name (`$3`) and assign resulting value to local variable `fname`
- `printf ...` - output our line of data; use `s` and `len` to pull the desired substring from `rd`
- `s += len` - add current `len` to `s` to get a new `s`tart position for next pass through the logic
- `END ...` - when all input processing is done, print our `newline` record to stdout

Running the above generates the following:

```
field1="12345678        "
filed2="A"
filed3="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                          "
field4="1234567890      "
newline="\n"
```

Comment: That solved my problem, and thanks for giving the comments for each and every line. Helped a lot to understand.